# R read.table() from pc vs mac

Tags: r, windows, macos

If you are a Mac user and you run the code below, you will get a data frame with 173,962 rows.  If you are a Windows user, your dataset will only have 8,999 rows. Can anyone tell me why?  And how can I get the data to read into R on my PC?

Here's my data: [.txt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40cc1rbrvimhxt7/Stream4_1.13.16t.txt?dl=0)

```
d<-read.table("Stream4_1.13.16t.txt", sep="", skip=10, quote = "", fill=T, header=F)
```

I am working with detection data created by a unique and uncommon software (a passive integrated transponder system, PIT) which sometimes "scrambles" a row of data and produces strange characters similar to those found in the Wingdings font. My files are text files that are space separated.  I had a hunch that these characters might be causing the read problem, but why would a Mac be different?

In an attempt to check if encoding needed to be changed, I ran the following:

```
d<-read.table("Stream4_1.13.16t.txt", sep="", fileEncoding="UTF-8", skip=10, quote = "", fill=T, header=F)
d<-read.table("Stream4_1.13.16t.txt", sep="", fileEncoding="latin1", skip=10, quote = "", fill=T, header=F)
```

and got this: Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'Stream4_1.13.16t.txt'

Comment: The "Note" section in `?read.table` talks about the interaction between text file encodings and operating systems. Maybe worth a look; I don't know the answer myself.

Comment: Thanks, Frank.  I played around with encoding a bit, but can't find an solution there.

Comment: I remember I had a similar problem once, it had something to do with  opening the file with a parameter "wb" Open for writing in binary mode. See the documentation of connections  (?connections).

Comment: I think you should open first a connection to the file with the parameter open"=wb" and then pass that object to read.table let me know if it works

Comment: You should do that in windows

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know the answer (although my suggestion below might have value) and am only using the answer box because this comment is too large and needs formatting capacity. (I'm the SO respondent who told you that this file was easy to read on a Mac.) This is the top of that file (using the downloaded data from your prior question):

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2016.01.13 16:42:02 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
u uh
  NEW  2016-01-08 16:27:25.52  171953
                        Total  171953

>up
Upload #1
Reader: S4  Site: AA
--------- upload 1 start ---------
E 2024-01-13 15:30:52.11 reader not responding
D 2016-01-08 16:27:34.83 00:00:00.38 HA      900_226000745066 A2    4    77
D 2016-01-08 16:27:34.41 00:00:00.00 HA      900_226000745066 A4    1   218
D 2016-01-08 16:27:34.59 00:00:00.62 HA      900_226000745066 A4    6     1
D 2016-01-08 16:27:34.41 00:00:00.00 HA      900_226000745066 A2    1    35
D 2016-01-08 16:27:34.59 00:00:00.62 HA      900_226000745066 A2    6     1
# snipped a bunch of lines
D 2016-01-08 16:29:26.86 00:00:00.86 HA      900_226000745060 A2    8    85
D 2016-01-08 16:29:28.21 00:00:00.32 HA      900_226000745060 A2    4     3
D 2016-01-08 16:29:28.70 00:00:00.12 HA      900_226000745060 A2    2     1
E 2016-01-08 16:36:00.00 date/time changed. Was 2016-01-08 16:29:37.80
D 2016-01-08 16:36:06.95 00:00:00.26 HA      900_226000745018 A2    3   136
D 2016-01-08 16:36:07.63 00:00:00.12 HA      900_226000745060 A2    2     3
D 2016-01-08 16:36:09.41 00:00:00.25 HA      900_226000745060 A2    3    13
D 2016-01-08 16:36:17.41 00:00:00.48 HA      900_226000745060 A2    5    65
D 2016-01-08 22:09:05.68 00:00:00.00 HA 00000 0 900 226000745000 2260007450?0 A4    1     0
D 2016-01-10 18:16:56.61 00:00:00.00 HA 00000 0 900 22600070 900 2260007450;1 A4    1     1
D 2016-01-08 16:36:30.62 00:00:00.19 HA      900_226000745060 A2    3     7
D 2016-01-08 16:36:31.04 00:00:00.31 HA      900_226000745060 A2    4     1
D 2016-01-08 16:36:33.02 00:00:00.12 HA      900_226000745066 A2    2    13
D 2016-01-08 16:36:41.07 00:00:00.13 HA      900_226000745066 A2    2    65
D 2016-01-10 15:38:39.74 00:00:00.00 HA 00000 0 900 22600074 900 2260007450?6 A2    1     1
D 2016-01-08 16:36:42.19 00:00:00.00 HA      900_226000745066 A2    1     1
D 2016-01-08 16:36:54.03 00:00:00.73 HA      900_226000745060 A2    7   101
D 2016-01-08 16:36:55.14 00:00:00.24 HA      900_226000745060 A2    3     2
D 2016-01-08 16:36:55.56 00:00:00.00 HA      900_226000745060 A2    1     1
D 2016-01-08 16:36:57.96 00:00:00.00 HA      900_226000745060 A2    1    19
```

Trying to read this file with read.table is a doomed hope. It is fixed width format for the lines starting with "D" which are the ones with data. A more sensible approach (once you figure out the encoding and font confusion) would be to use `readLines` to creae a `txt_obj`, create a selection vector with `grepl("^D ", txt_obj)` and then parse with read.fwf.

Answer (score 0):

I received help from an outside source who suggested using the readr package.
The code below works and imports all the rows of data.

```
library(readr)
d<-read_table("Stream4_1.13.16t.txt", col_names = F, na = "NA", skip = 10)
```